# how to solve [IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Tags: mysql, odbc, asterisk, elastix

when I try this command isql  : ***-v MySQL-asterisk*** to show if ODBC Is connected seccuseful with database in ELASTIX , I get this msg : [IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need setup /etc/odbc.ini and /etc/unixodbc.ini accordinly to your database connection